# Baffling error filtering Django objects of derived class by values in foreign key linked class

Tags: python, django, django-models

An app I am converting from Django 1.10 to 3.0 contains classes defined as follows (including only relevant fields) :

```
class DataSet(models.Model):
      :::

class SurveyRunDataSet(DataSet):
    survey_run = models.ForeignKey('survey.SurveyRun', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, ..)
       :::
```

But the following call, which worked fine at Django 1.10, now fails at Django 3.0 :

```
survey_run_id = ..

report_ids = (SurveyRunDataSet.objects.
    filter(survey_run_id=survey_run_id,report__report_type=AnalysisReport.SUMMARY).
        values_list('report_id', flat=True).distinct())
```

The error is :

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'survey_run_id' into field. Choices are: aggregatedataset, filtereddataset, flush_date, id, materalised_source_data_set, materialiseddataset, name, primary_dataset, psession_source_data_set, psessiondataset, report, report_id, source_data_set, surveyrundataset
```

Most of the above choices are other classes that inherit from "DataSet". So Django goes delving upwards in a bizarre wrong direction in the class structure, while missing a field item which is right in front of its nose, in the very model the objects.filter() is being applied to. It makes absolutely no sense!

The model tables in postgres are exactly as expected :

```
# \d dataset_surveyrundataset

 dataset_ptr_id | integer               | not null
 status         | character varying(10) | not null
 base_dataset   | boolean               | not null
 schema_mapping | text                  | not null
 survey_run_id  | integer               |

"dataset_surveyrundat_survey_run_id_8e235a8a_fk_survey_su" FOREIGN KEY (survey_run_id) REFERENCES survey_surveyrun(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED


# \d survey_surveyrun

id     | integer  | not null default nextval('survey_surveyrun_id_seq'::regclass)
  :::
```

I tried changing the clause "survey_run_id=survey_run_id" to "survey_run__id=survey_run_id", and several other plausible looking forms. But so far nothing has worked.

Any ideas? What is the code doing wrong (which wasn't wrong at Django 1.10 !!)

Comment: Thinking about the message some more, it appears Django may be starting its search for matching survey_run_id in the "DataSet" model, and extending downwards and sideways recursively to all models that derive from that, but for some unfathomable reason carefully avoiding "SurveyRunDataSet" ! (I omitted the other derived models for brevity and because they didn't seem relevant.)

Comment: Cannot recreate this behavior using Python 3.8.2, Django 3.0.6, and the snippets of code  presented here. Currently guessing that there's something else involved, either within the view trying to execute this query or definitions within the model (e.g. custom manager)

Suggest trying this query from within the Django shell to limit the scope of the issue.